# Specifying timeout for python-requests, when using PreparedRequest

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, concurrent.futures

I know for a PreparedRequest, we specifiy the timeout in `session.send` call, where `session` can be an instance of `requests.Session` class, as I've already seen here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/

But I need to put the timeout before I do the send. Somewhat inherently, to the PreparedRequest object. Because I'm using the `session.send` method as map function, to map to PreparedRequest instances.

```
def async_req2resp(reqs, session):
    responses = []
    try:
        with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
            for response in executor.map(session.send, requests):
                responses.append(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print('async_requests2responses exception: ' + str(e))
    return responses
```

Now I need to specify the timeout somehow. How can I do it?
The above code is wrapped inside a method. I am getting the `session` object as an argument. Is there a way I can set the timeout for all the requests that will be sent with the `session` object, before the parallel execution of session.send happens?

Thank you.

Comment: What is "sendit"? Does it accept arbitrary keyword args for the function/method it is calling?

Answer (score 1):

I'm waiting for your answer about `sendit` but until then, let me give you some information that should help you get the rest of the way there.

If you have a PreparedRequest object as `request` then you can do `session.send(request, timeout=timeout_val)` where `timeout_val` is whatever the value of the timeout is that you want.

With that in mind, this question becomes, "How do I pass that to `sendit` with each request?" and that question I don't have the answer for.

Side note:

You've tagged this with `concurrent.futures` which makes me suspect you're trying to optimize your application that uses this method. With that in mind, you should avoid appending to a list at all costs. You should, instead, try to do the following:

```
responses = []
try:
    responses = list(sendit.map(session.send, requests))
# etc.
```

If you figure out how to pass the timeout parameter to sendit, feel free to suggest an edit to this answer to update it to be complete.

---

With the updated information in the question, I can more accurately answer your question.

Before you call `executor.map` you should do the following:

```
import functools

timedout_send = functools.partial(session.send, timeout=my_timeout)

try:
    list(executor.map(timedout_send, requests))
# ...
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. I've updated my code snippet. The thing is, I'm trying to parallelize the requests made from my code. And the code updated is a simpler version of how I do it.

Comment: @bad_keypoints I've updated this with the best way to do what you want. Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out when I have time to go back to that part of code and I'll tick your answer then. :)